# Facebook c# sdk get users email

Tags: facebook, oauth, facebook-c#-sdk

I have a site which is using facebook for auth. I want to gather some basic info when a user signs up including their email address.

The code i have for the login is standard:

```
public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        var oAuthClient = new FacebookOAuthClient();
        oAuthClient.AppId = AppSettings.GetConfigurationString("appId");
        oAuthClient.RedirectUri = new Uri(AppSettings.GetConfigurationString("redirectUrl"));
        var loginUri = oAuthClient.GetLoginUrl(new Dictionary<string, object> { { "state", returnUrl } });
        return Redirect(loginUri.AbsoluteUri);
    }
```

How do i add the request to access permissions in that? Or do i do it another way?

Comment: Not quite duplicate, but along the same lines: [Facebook connect, email address?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986578/facebook-connect-email-address)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A snoop at the sdk code and i came up wiht:

```
 public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        var oAuthClient = new FacebookOAuthClient();
        oAuthClient.AppId = AppSettings.GetConfigurationString("appId");
        oAuthClient.RedirectUri = new Uri(AppSettings.GetConfigurationString("redirectUrl"));

        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        parameters["state"] = returnUrl;
        parameters["scope"] = "email";

        var loginUri = oAuthClient.GetLoginUrl(parameters);
        return Redirect(loginUri.AbsoluteUri);
    }
```

not tested it yet and the missus is shouting at me for working late so will have to test tomoz :)

Answer (score 10):

You need to use the `email` permission (the full list is here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/ )

The way to add permissions to the authorization is by appending a comma separated list to `&scope=` , e.g.:

`https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL&scope=email,read_stream`

---

**Update:** As you marked, the parameters are passed to the `GetLoginUrl()` method, although in the codeplex forum they also used `ExchangeCodeForAccessToken()`, which you might want to take a look at also.

A couple of examples using the C# SDK:

http://blog.prabir.me/post/Facebook-CSharp-SDK-Writing-your-first-Facebook-Application.aspx

[Facebook .NET SDK: How to authenticate with ASP.NET MVC 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5075290/facebook-net-sdk-how-to-authenticate-with-asp-net-mvc-2)

http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/discussions/244568

Comment: yeah - i need to know how to do that using the c# facebook sdk: http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/