# Facebook login in window phone 8.1 application

Tags: facebook-graph-api, windows-phone-8.1

I am working with a window mobile application (8.1) and in that, I have to integrate Facebook login/Registration.  That functionality works fine but I am unable to get user mobile number and email address. I get only two things when user login through Facebook **"Full Name", "fb_id"**.
I set following permissions to get user basic info - **"public_profile", "email"**.
Please help me with this. 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook c# sdk get users email](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5625532/facebook-c-sharp-sdk-get-users-email)

Comment: I am using in window mobile application not a desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To integrate Facebook in your windows phone 8.1 project you can use 
 http://bsubramanyamraju.blogspot.in/2014/12/windowsphone-store-81-facebook.html
this block.

And to get email id just add **fields=email**.
Like this

"  **FacebookClient fbclient = new Facebook.FacebookClient(ObjFBHelper.AccessToken+ "&fields=email");** "

I think it works